# docker-compose up command not working on console

Tags: docker-compose

I have 5 images and try to run docker images through `docker-compose up`, but it is showing nothing on the console.
while running the `docker-compose --version` it is showing nothing.

Comment: Have you installed `docker-compose` or is it that you have installed `docker-engine` only?

Comment: Do you get any output from `which docker-compose`? If not, it isn't installed.

Answer (score 3):

docker-compose does not come bundled with the docker-engine. You need to install it separately after installing the engine. Follow the instructions given in this link:

> https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/